# automatic, implicit, easy and reliable source revision indicator for maven+jenkins multi-module SNAPSHOT builds?

Tags: maven, version-control, jenkins, release-management

I currently have a set of maven  modules whose versions are set to 1.0-SNAPSHOT designating the current trunk. Those modules get built inside jenkins separately, share the same SVN repo, but do not share a single checkout, so I cannot just take the svn revision of the build's checkout revision -- and that poses my main problem: I usually wait until all activity in Jenkins stops and everything is green (or blue), then I know that everything is ok and that the final build product's svn revision is consistent with all trunk-based modules' source revisions.

If you cannot follow me up to this point, please tell.

Is there any way to improve that, ie. make it more automatic? Two potential pitfalls I can see with that solution: first, Jenkins dependency resolution may be broken, out of date etc. That would lead to an inconsistent mapping between final product revision and possible outdated dependency revisions (because their build was not triggered). Second, there may be some race between final product build and a new source svn commit.

Question: how do you go about that? Yes, I know, it would be cleaner to use explicit release management, but because the builds won't leave some inner circle, it seems to be unnecessary overhead. Is there any way to propagate each and every module's svn revision and dump all dependencies' svn revision in the final product build using something similar to "mvn dependency:tree"? Is it possible to assign snapshot versions a source code revision without having to change the snapshot version references upon changing it?

Update:

here is some solution to store http://www.jayway.com/2012/04/07/continuous-deployment-versioning-and-git/ svn revision inside the MANIFEST etc., however it has a drawback: how do I make sure that these revisions get included into the final build?

Ideally, the svn revision would be appended to the "1.0-SNAPSHOT" revision identifier, ie. "1.0-SNAPSHOT-4783", however, that breaks the ability to reference the latest SNAPSHOT build by simply using "1.0-SNAPSHOT" in dependent modules... I could use [1.0-SNAPSHOT,) in dependent modules to reference SNAPSHOT builds, but it seems that such SNAPSHOT identifiers are not treated as SNAPSHOT by Nexus (I cannot deploy them to a snapshot repo).

Comment: Are all these artifacts located within the same subversion repository?

Comment: You can use a pipeline with the svn revision number which will given from one step to the next step...The start of the pipeline could be a trigger job which just is used to get the revision from the repository and trigger afterwards the appropriate jobs with the revision number. This makes sure using the same svn revision number.

Comment: As far as I understand your solution, it would defy the separation into different modules for performance reasons: you would need to rebuild all modules with every svn commit, right?